# How to iterate through audio files when converting into mfccs

Tags: python-3.x, mfcc

I am a beginner, i am converting audio files into mfccs , i have done it for one file but don't know how to iterate it through all dataset. I have multiple folders in Training folder ,one of them is 001(0) from which one wav file is converted.I want to convert all folder's wav files present in Training folder

```
import os
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from glob import glob
import scipy.io.wavfile as wav
from python_speech_features import mfcc, logfbank

# Read the input audio file
(rate,sig) = wav.read('Downloads/DataVoices/Training/001(0)/001000.wav')


# Take the first 10,000 samples for analysis
sig = sig[:10000]
features_mfcc = mfcc(sig,rate)

# Print the parameters for MFCC
print('\nMFCC:\nNumber of windows =', features_mfcc.shape[0])
print('Length of each feature =', features_mfcc.shape[1])

# Plot the features
features_mfcc = features_mfcc.T
plt.matshow(features_mfcc)
plt.title('MFCC')

# Extract the Filter Bank features
features_fb = logfbank(sig, rate)

# Print the parameters for Filter Bank 
print('\nFilter bank:\nNumber of windows =', features_fb.shape[0])
print('Length of each feature =', features_fb.shape[1])

# Plot the features
features_fb = features_fb.T
plt.matshow(features_fb)
plt.title('Filter bank')

plt.show()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use glob recursively with wildcards to find all of the wav files.

```
for f in glob.glob(r'Downloads/DataVoices/Training/**/*.wav', recursive=True):
     (rate,sig) = wav.read(f)
     # Rest of your code
```

Comment: Thank you very much. You made my day. God bless you!